# How to only print a string in Python when the contents update?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a program in Python that can keep track of the songs I have played on my VLC media player. So when I spend a night listening to my playlist on shuffle, I can go back and see what it played.

My idea is to have the program read the titles of the windows I have open and find the window that has "VLC media player" in it. If the title of the window is new, it will print the window title and if the same song is still playing (thus the title is the same) it does nothing. This will update at an interval, currently set to 5 seconds and like so print a playlist, which I could ultimately export to a text file.

However, if I run this code it will still print the song_title every 5 seconds even if it is the same as previous_song. And when the song changes, it will keep the previous song titles in the variable previous_song instead of replacing it.

What am I doing wrong here? And maybe are there ways of doing this better?

```
import time
EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible

titles = []


def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):
    if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
        buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
        GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
        titles.append(buff.value)
    return True

while True:
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)
    VLC = "VLC media player"
    PreviousSong = ''

    for i in titles:
        if VLC in i:
            SongTitle = i
            if not SongTitle in PreviousSong:
                PreviousSong = SongTitle
                print(PreviousSong)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: I don't know about VLC but many players have a programmatic API which lets you query the currently playing song as well as often the history etc. Trying to pull that out of the window title seems very brittle.

Comment: Quick googling gets me https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HTTP_requests/